# What happened to Objective-C's "stringWithFormat:" method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I define

```
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4d", 543210];
```

then `testString` is `@"543210"`, instead of `@"3210"`

This used to work in **Xcode v4.3.1** but now I upgraded to **v4.6** and it stopped working.

Any ideas?

Comment: In xcode 4.6 it is  `543210`. clean your target...and try again

Comment: what you want print here?

Comment: Note that this is not related to the version of Xcode. If anything, it's related to the version of CoreFoundation and Foundation (but I doubt even that).

Comment: I want to trim the integer to 4 digits as the %4d indicates. So it should be 3210. It worked in xcode 4.3.

Comment: TSK... incomplete question... :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: What's missing?

Comment: @PeterHosey: I couldn't understand his question unless he commented he want to truncate 5 form 543210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> then testString is `@"543210"`, instead of `@"3210"`

That's the correct behavior anyway. The `%Nd` format specifier doesn't limit the field with of the number being formatted - it only pads it with space if the field with is greater than the number of characters required to represent the number. If you got `3210` previously, that's erroneous.

If you want to format a number so at most its last four digits are printed, then you can do something like this:

```
NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 543210]; // or whatever
if (numStr.length > 4) {
    numStr = [numStr substringFromIndex:numStr.length - 4];
}
```

Comment: So H2CO3, do I have to use substringWithRange to trim the string down to 4 then?

Comment: @shredding Exactly, I just added that part as well.

Comment: What about this NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4d", 543210];  numStr = [numStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(numStr.length - 4, 4)]; //without the if statement

Comment: @shredding What if the string is 3 characters long? You've suddenly got a huge `NSException` thrown at your head.

Comment: b/c i used %4d, it will force it to 4 characters long if the original string is 3 character long.

Comment: @shredding And when you change it, it will break :) Better be safe. One `if` doesn't hurt.

Comment: i wanted to answer this question :( hardly found one question which i was knowing little but while typing answer i see answer is already posted and accepted :[

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, has the benefit of being short:

```
NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4d", 543210 % 10000];
```

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder, so if you `% 10000` you get the 4 least significant digits.